# Fit more tracks than 8 in the Spotify Play Button widget

Tags: iframe, embed, spotify

I have this site:
http://www.johnseabrook.com/playlists/

The problem is my client wants to show the full playlist (some have up to 15 songs). Right now it's limited to only 8 songs and a max height of 720px per Spotify. Is there a hack around this? I tried changing the Iframe height in pixels and percent to be larger but nothing has worked. Thank you in advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way the Spotify Play Button works is that you actually need to increase the `width` as well, e.g.

```html
<iframe src="https://embed.spotify.com/?uri=spotify:user:1215385803:playlist:1BSFYwDOOQEGCA71QUJJw9" width="720" height="1280" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Comment: Thank you Michael you are a life saver it totally worked! I didn't realize it was that easy!

Comment: I have to give some credit to @JMPerez, it was actually he who found the solution and I stole the points without hesitation.